# Problem connecting to rabbitmq inside docker container

Tags: docker, go, rabbitmq

I'm writing a simple go application to test working with rabbitmq. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    var conn *amqp.Connection
    var err error

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        conn, err = amqp.Dial("amqp://dev:test@rabbitmq:5672/")
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        log.Println(err)
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to connect to RabbitMQ: %v", err)
    }

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "hello", // name
        false,   // durable
        false,   // delete when unused
        false,   // exclusive
        false,   // no-wait
        nil,     // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    body := "Hello World!"
    err = ch.Publish(
        "",     // exchange
        q.Name, // routing key
        false,  // mandatory
        false,  // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            ContentType: "text/plain",
            Body:        []byte(body),
        })
    log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s", body)
    failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        true,   // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

    forever := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
        }
    }()

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
    <-forever
}
```

The problem is that the rabbitmq service seems to start and work fine.I can also enter management plugin web application.But my application always give me this error:
`024/01/22 13:16:33 Failed to connect to RabbitMQ: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5672: connect: connection refused`
Which obviously means that I cannot connect to RabbitMQ.
Here is the DockerFile:

```
FROM golang:latest

LABEL maintainer="Anatoliy"

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o main .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./main"]
```

And here is docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbit"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: dev
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: test
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmqctl", "status"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
```

Also I just started only rabbitmq in docker, and I was able to connect to rabbitmq, starting my application outside of docker, with this connection line:
`conn, err = amqp.Dial("amqp://dev:test@0.0.0.0:5672/")`
With this connection line application was working correctly. I don't understand how to setup my application to work correctly inside the docker.

Comment: Rabbitmq isn't running at `127.0.0.1`. It's running on a host named `rabbitmq` (because that's the service name in your compose file).

Comment: That's correct, I understand that. But for some reason, my program when starts only show this error message:
Failed to connect to RabbitMQ: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5672: connect: connection refused
Instead of actual received message from the queue

Comment: And also the connection string is correct: 
conn, err = amqp.Dial("amqp://dev:test@rabbitmq:5672/")

Comment: Is there a specific reason for attempting to establish a connection to RabbitMQ within a for loop? It seems unnecessary to reconnect to RabbitMQ every 5 seconds if the connection has already been established, doesn't it?

Comment: In my Docker Compose setup, I've added a health check to the RabbitMQ service and used depends_on in myapplication service to ensure that it only starts after the RabbitMQ service is healthy. 

However,as far as I understand it's possible that the RabbitMQ service is not fully ready to accept connections even after it's marked as healthy. To handle this, I tried to modify my application to retry the connection a few times before giving up. 

But still no luck

Comment: Loop logic should be `if err == nil { break }` (your code continues to retry whether there is an error or not). Having made that change, I tested things on my machine (copying everything from your question) and it all ran fine (` Received a message: Hello World!`).

Comment: That's really strange. I copy pasted your part of code, and replaced mine and still get the same:
2024/01/22 19:20:58 Failed to connect to RabbitMQ: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5672: connect: connection refused
Do you have any special settings in your Docker? I'm using Docker Desktop on win 10

Comment: Also I tried instead of loop writing just simple connection string like this:
conn, err = amqp.Dial("amqp://dev:test@rabbitmq:5672/")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to RabbitMQ: %v", err)
}
Still no luck

Comment: I'm running the latest docker on Win 11 (so should be the same). It looks like there may be a DNS issue (I can't see anything that should result in the use of `127.0.0.1`). Perhaps try ` docker compose exec app /bin/sh` (to run a shell in the container) then `getent hosts rabbitmq` and see what address is output.

Comment: I can confirm that the code as provided runs as expected on my Mac.

Answer (score -1):

Provided listings is working fine (without any changes), so probably you have some kind of issues with your environment.

Rabbitmq mentioned in docker-compose unable to start because you have another rabbitmq in docker or on your host. To stop all running containers do this `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)`. Also, you should check that you have no rabbit on your host machine. Or, you can just remove the section with port exposing (remove this lines `- "5672:5672"`, `- "15672:15672"` from compose file).